# keep running process/refresh in bash

Tags: bash, process, tail

I want to keep an eye on the output of a particular command, say `ps aux | grep guest`.

I'm waiting for it to change. Is there any way I could do something like the `tail` command does to a file?

Max

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
watch "ps aux | grep guest"
```

Comment: whoa. no wayyyyyyyyyy! how do i specify the interval?

Comment: @tekknolagi: Use the `--interval` flag.

Comment: @tekknolagi: You can use `-n seconds`. From the man page:
`watch runs command repeatedly, displaying its output and errors (the first screenfull).  This allows you to watch the program output change over time.  By default, the program is run every 2 seconds; use -n or --interval to specify a different interval. Normally, this interval is interpreted as the amout of time between the completion of one run of command and the beginning of the next run. However, with the -p or --precise option, you can make watch attempt to run command every interval seconds.`

Comment: A simple `watch ps` works fine as well if you don't have too many processes (each can be monitored together).